# Matrix in Struct in C

Tags: c, matrix, struct

I am trying to store matrices in a LinkedList. But I got an error, code can compile but can't run. Probably about memory allocation but I couldn't figure it out.

My struct is like that:

```
typedef struct node {
     int** matrix;
     struct node *next;
} node;

struct node *head;
struct node *tail;
```

I tried to initialize the struct like that:

```
struct node *init(void) {
     head = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *head);
     tail = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *head);

     head->next = tail;
     tail->next = tail;
     return head;
}
```

And I have a matrix full of 1s:

```
int **mat = (int **) malloc(N * sizeof(int *));

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    mat[i] = (int *) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        mat[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

But when I tried to append it on the list, program has crashed.

I tried to append like that:

```
struct node *l1;
l1 = init();

l1 = append(mat, "t1", N);
int** a3 = returnNode(0, l1);
```

And finally, my append and returnNode functions are like that:

```
struct node *append(int** mat, char* name, int N) {
     struct node *ptr;

     struct node *t;
     ptr = head;
     while (ptr->next != tail)
          ptr = ptr->next;
     t = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *t);

     t->matrix = (int**) malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
     int i,j;
     for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
             t->matrix[i][j] = (int)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
         }
     }
     t->matrix = mat;
     t->next = tail;

     ptr->next = t;
     return ptr;
}

int** returnNode(int index, struct node *ptr) {
     int i;
     struct node *t;
     t = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *t);
     t = head;
     for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
         t = t->next;
     }

     return t->matrix;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "matrix" is typically a synonym for a 2D array. If that is your intention, something like `int **` is not a 2D array and cannot be used as one. Using a true 2D array makes the code clearer and allocatio/freeing straight forward. It also can(!) add a performance gain.

Comment: I get the N value from a text file. So it should be dynamic, because of that I am using int**

Comment: 'But I got an error, code can compile but can't run' - what error, why will it not run?   Unclear what you're asking....

Comment: What did you find when you ran it under your debugger?  How far did it get?

Comment: Where is main()?   Where is your MCVE?

Comment: How are you testing it?  How do you call those functions?  How do we know that your arguments are valid?

Comment: I created `int **mat` in main. Also I called append in main. Main function is not necessary here, because my problem is not about main. I just cannot use int** in struct. I ran the program and I get "program.exe has stopped working" error.

Comment: I created a matrix (mat). It is filled with 1s, it's true. I send it to append function. After that I tried to get it with returnNode function. There is something wrong between this steps, I'm sure about that.

Comment: "I get the `N` value from a text file. So it should be dynamic, because of that I am using `int**`" - 1) use markup! 2) How is that opposed to what I wrote? You very well can allocate a multi-dimensional array dynamically. There are various Q&A about that here. Just ignore thos using something like `type **`

Comment: Debugger......... which line causes the error/crash that you have not yet detailed?

Comment: @MartinJames This is the problem, I cannot see that error/crash either :) Because of that I tell you it's probably about memory allocation

Comment: I quit Windows and tried it on a Linux machine. The error is like that: **cast from pointer to integer of different size** The line is `t->matrix[i][j] = (int)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));` that one

Comment: I solved that problem. All I have is a shiny, handsome "Segmentation Fault"

Comment: This is just a general note on creating programs like this in C/C++. Write the code in small pieces and run constantly. This avoids a lot of the where is this seg fault stuff and other problems. A lot of problems come from people writing everything then trying to make it work from there instead of developing incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that:

> Cast from pointer to integer of different size

on

```
t->matrix[i][j] = (int)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
```

**Solution:-**

Here you are trying to convert an address to an integer value and assign that to an integer variable location.

The actual problem is here:

```
(int)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
```

malloc returns a pointer, you should cast its type accordingly and assign that respectively.

Comment: I solved it. Now the only problem is "Segmentation Fault"

Comment: segmentation fault means you are going beyond the memory you have allocated. Can you please put the minimal part of your code which is causing that fault?

Comment: My code is like that. From "And I have a matrix..." part to "..And finally..." part in my question is in main. There is nothing related with memory allocation

Comment: Even in that part, you are using `malloc` and you are using loops to access memory. Also, I would advise using `free`...

Comment: Please try to debug your code and narrow down the place where you have segfault. You could just put `printf` statements to see how far can you move without the fault.

Comment: Debugging worked, thanks very much. It's such a rookie mistake.

Comment: I am glad to know that... hope you wouldn't mind accepting the answer.